# Netty 5 Secure WebSockets running on Android causes NoClassDefFoundError for io/netty/channel/DefaultChannelId

Tags: android, ssl, websocket, socket.io, netty

I am using Netty 5 alpha release on android to write a secure web socket client.

But at the run time I am getting NoClassDefFoundError for io/netty/channel/DefaultChannelId.

The class is already exists in the Jar file. Can anybody tell me why this issue is happening.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/channel/DefaultChannelId
```

Comment: Could you paste the stack trace of the NoClassDefFoundError? I guess Android failed to load the DefaultChannelId class due to some runtime problem.

Comment: we are also facing the same issue...can anyone help to solve this issue